# How to get the url path in a spring controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Supose I have a controller like this in a Spring project:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="mapping_one")
public class AcessoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="mapping_two")
    public ModelAndView mapping_two() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("view");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

and supose too the url informed by user is something like that:

```
http://webapp/mapping_one/mapping_two/some_string_here/
```

Is there any way to capture this `some_string_here` inside the method `mapping_two` from controller above (the type of returned value can be different)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the [@PathVariable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "mapping_two/{theString}")
public ModelAndView mappingTwo(@PathVariable String theString) {
    ...
}
```